# How to put theme modifications into a personal layer?

Tags: spacemacs, themes

For example I want to put `(setq spacemacs-theme-org-height nil)` into a personal layer, but that doesn't work.  I can only put the setting into `dotspacemacs/user-init`.  The reason seems to be Spacemace has already initiated the theme before loading layers.

Is there a way to put the theme settings into a personal layer？